# Identifying missing elements in a list in R

Tags: r

I have a named list of vectors created from running `grep()`. I want to find those elements for which no value was found, or for which a bunch of NAs were found. How do I do this?

I tried, but didn't go too far.

```
MyList<-c("Hello World", "a123 234","Hi world","a12345678 09876","publ school")
look_New<-c("world","a123","a1234","121314","pub school",NA) #this was generated using different code.
look_Old<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f") #this was generated using different code.
Look<-data.frame(look_New,look_Old,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Result<-lapply(Look$look_New, grep, x = MyList,ignore.case=TRUE)
names(Result)<-Look$look_Old

#which elements are null?
Look$look_Old[which(sapply(Result,length)==0)]
```

**2 Questions:**

**Question: 1)**

The problem is that the above code doesn't show me `f` which has a bunch of `NA`s. However, it does show me `d` and `e`

The expected output would be:

```
d
e
f
```

**Question 2:**

Is there anyway I can replace so many NAs with zero vector? i.e. if I run `Results$f`, it should show below (just as I would get by running `Results$e`:

```
Result$f
integer(0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many NAs constitute "a bunch"?

Comment: @Rich - Thanks for your question...It could be `>=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
v1 <- sapply(Result, function(x) length(x)==0 | all (is.na(x)))
names(v1)[v1]
#[1] "d" "e" "f"
```

---

Or use `Filter`

```
names(Filter(function(x) !length(x)|all(is.na(x)), Result))
```

Comment: thanks! Here's what I tried: `lapply(Result,function(x){x<-x[!is.na(x)]})`. Now the above code in my post works!

Comment: @watchtower  Based on your code, `names(Filter(Negate(length), lapply(Result,function(x){x<-x[!is.na(x)]})))` should also work

Answer (score 1):

Use `lengths()` after removing `NA` values:

```
names(Result)[!lengths(lapply(Result, na.omit))]
#[1] "d" "e" "f"
```

Comment: That's a slick idea.  Could even be shortened again to `names(Result)[!lengths(lapply(Result, na.omit))]`